# How are Japanese names romanized in localization?

Tags: translation, readings

I've read that that romanizing Japanese names can be particularly difficult, due to the fact that the kanji that make them up have multiple pronunciations, or even a completely random one.

However, seeing Japanese media - particularly video games - translated to English makes me wonder how each and every name in the credits becomes romanized. How is this usually done? Is the kana used to pronounce one's name easily accessible for professionals? Is this pronunciation gathered on a case by case basis? Or does "guesswork" need to be done, with possible mistakes occurring? If readings are provided, how is this information usually transferred?

Comment: For a professionally translated product, names in the credits don't have to be guessed at. The company that created the original work can just provide all the readings, so it's not really a matter of translation.

Comment: Many Japanese games, though probably not most, also have text in Roman letters in the credits to begin with.